# pgr_Dijkstra: iterate/loop through a table with multiple OD pairs one-by-one

Tags: pgrouting, iterator, loop, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a table with 2 columns: column A with the startvertex and column B with endvertex.

How can I do a **OD pairs shortest path**?

It is with a **loop** I suppose, but how can this loop be implemented into pgr_Dijkstra? It's impossible  do to all the OD pairs manually, so an **iteration** is necessary.

I have already a working query for pgr_Dijkstra for a single point-to-point, but the problem is to do it for **all the OD-pairs one-by-one**.

Answer (score 0):

`pgr_Dijkstra` caan also solve `1->n` and `n->m` shortest path.
When you look at the function documentation you will see, that you can pass an array of start or end ID's.

`SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edge_table',
    ARRAY[2,11], ARRAY[3,5],
    FALSE
);`

http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.4/en/pgr_dijkstra.html#pgr-dijkstra-many-to-many

Comment: This is for many×many, not pair to pair.